# cakephp choosing language by url

Tags: php, cakephp, localization, cakephp-1.3

what I am trying to achieve is described here http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/11/28/cakephp-url-based-language-switching-for-i18n-and-l10n-internationalization-and-localization/ 
but I can not get it working.

The router configurations looks like this:

```
Router::connect('/registered/:language/:controller/:action/*',
 array('prefix' => 'registered', 'registered' => true, 'layout'=> 'registered'),
 array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
```

butw when I try to go to `www.example.com/registered/cze/packages` I get:

`Error: CzeController could not be found.`

I am using cake 1.3, not 1.2 as the author, that may be the problem, but what do I need to change in order for this to work?

Edit:

```
$this->Session->write('Config.language','cze');
```

This code works and when used in the controller changes the language of the site, but I need to get it working according to the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL `www.example.com/registered/cze/packages` does not match the route `/registered/:language/:controller/:action/*`, since the `:action` segment is empty. Therefore, the URL falls through to the standard route, where `registered` is recognized as the prefix and `cze` as the controller.

You'll need to create a "shorter" `/registered/:language/:controller` route as well to catch "abbreviated" URLs.