# cakephp choosing language by url - part 2

Tags: php, cakephp, localization, cakephp-1.3

Ok, so I have now working localization based on URL (`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550670/cakephp-choosing-language-by-url`), but how to create a link that will change the language? I've tried

```
<?php echo $html->link('English', array('language'=>'eng')); ?>
```

but all it does is that it adds `language:eng` at the end of the URL (`www.example.com/blah/blah/language:eng` instead of `www.example.com/eng/blah/blah`) and does not switch the language at all.

The routes now look like this:

```
Router::connect('/registered/:language/:controller',  
                array('prefix' => 'registered', 'registered' => true, 'layout'=> 'registered'),
                array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
Router::connect('/registered/:language/:controller/:action/*', 
                array('prefix' => 'registered', 'registered' => true, 'layout'=> 'registered'),
                array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
```

I've also overriden the url method in app_helper:

```
    function url($url = null, $full = false) {
        if(!isset($url['language']) && isset($this->params['language'])) {
          $url['language'] = $this->params['language'];
        }
        return parent::url($url, $full);
   }
```

How to set the link to work the way it should be?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing :language from your router urls.

Not tested, but it should work as your urls already getting named param :language

```
Router::connect('/registered/:controller',  
                array('prefix' => 'registered', 'registered' => true, 'layout'=> 'registered'),
                array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
Router::connect('/registered/:controller/:action/*', 
                array('prefix' => 'registered', 'registered' => true, 'layout'=> 'registered'),
                array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
```

Keep url override method to ensure you accept both type of GET variables.

Comment: well if I remove the language param from router url, the urls won't work the way I want. I pretty much need them to look like www.example.com/eng/blah/blah rather than www.example.com/blah/blah/language:eng